# Uid/Gid privileged LXC container : systemd lxc-start failed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: systemd, lxc, uid

I would like to create & start LXC container for specific UID & GID for below purpose.

Login to root user(sudo user) , Do lxc-create of container, then do lxc-start of the container with same root user id. while staring container I need to start all the process inside the container with low privilege(un-priv) user id in which access to the user is restricted to only container and not to host.basically when I say ps -axu , I should be able to see low privilege user id for all the container process.

PS : my host which is VM with ubuntu 16.04 LTS is systemd init system and my container(type busybox) will be started with systemd services . for that I have modified busybox template as below
Code:

```
lxc.init_cmd=/lib/systemd/systemd
```

and also removed all rcS & inittab related scripts in the busybox default template

and for user id map , I have changed as below in my template
Code:

```
   lxc.id_map=u 0 165536 65536
   lxc.id_map=g 0 165536 65536
```

after that I just followed below steps

Container created normally with below commend (and I cross checked config file at /var/lib/lxc/testecho_uid/config to make sure that all my template changes are reflected or not, found ok)
Code:

```
sudo lxc-create -n testecho_uid -t busybox_systemd_uid
```

Entered below command to start the container with foreground
Code:

```
sudo lxc-start -n testecho_uid -F
```

Error is :

```
vijay@vijay-VirtualBox:~$ sudo lxc-start -n testecho_uid -F
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: cgfsng_create: 1072 No such file or directory - Failed to create /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd//lxc/testecho_uid: No such file or directory
                                         lxc-start: cgfsng.c: cgfsng_create: 1072 No such file or directory - Failed to create /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd//lxc/testecho_uid-1: No such file or directory
                                                                                    newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
                                 lxc-start: start.c: lxc_spawn: 1161 failed to set up id mapping
                                                                                                lxc-start: start.c: __lxc_start: 1353 failed to spawn 'testecho_uid'
                                                    newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/memory//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/pids//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/devices//lxc/testecho_uid-2
newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [165536-231072) not allowed
lxc-start: conf.c: userns_exec_1: 4315 Error setting up child mappings
lxc-start: cgfsng.c: recursive_destroy: 983 Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer//lxc/testecho_uid-2
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 344 The container failed to start.
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 348 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

Can anyone please tell me whether I am missing anything here.

below are my ubuntu 16.04 setup for uid & gid
Code:

```
vijay@vijay-VirtualBox:~$ sudo cat  /etc/subgid
vijay:100000:65536
usrlxc:165536:65536
vijay:165536:65537
```

Code:

```
vijay@vijay-VirtualBox:~$ sudo cat  /etc/subuid
vijay:100000:65536
usrlxc:165536:65536
vijay:165536:65537
```

---

if above my question is not clear , please see below one more question similar to same scenario.
Is there a way to access(lxc start & attach) unprivileged container from root user or sudo user . 
That is , I have created , started and attached un-priv container using lxc user(not sudo user/root user) by login into lxc user without any issue. Now I would like to start & attach the lxc user created un-priv container from root user or sudo user.

Is that possible? if yes please let me know how to do that?. 
I checked lxc-ls from sudo/root user and it just listed only the containers created by sudo user and does not display the container created by lxc user.

or

All the processes/threads of Privilege container can be executed/run for specific UID(eg: lxc user) by root/sudo user while doing lxc-start or by any means?
I also tried by giving below lxc user uid & gid in config(ultimately changing busybox template). it gave above comment error.
Code:
 lxc.id_map=u 0 165536 65536
  lxc.id_map=g 0 165536 65536
I tried all the possible way , but no luck , please educate me this topic.

Below are user detail in my ubuntu desktop 
lxc user --> "usrlxc" which I have created as part of un-priv container creation experiment.
Sudo user --> "vijay" - this is sudo user in my ubuntu 16.04 Virtual box machine.
root user --> # which all of you aware
Please let me know if any information from my ubuntu setup or lxc config

Answer (score 1):

I dont find any option to map UID/GIP for privileged container with so far experiment wrt LXC .
From that i can understand that UID/GID mapping can be done for non-priv container only.Correct me if i am wrong.
In other-way , we cannot access un-priv container from root user(or sudo user) , that is if we do 
sudo lxc-ls , it will only list the root/sudo user created container and will not display un-priv container created by low-privileged user(usrlxc in my case). So , we can not do lxc-start/attach the un-priv container from root/sudo user.

so , i am trying to manage using systemD service files to achieve.not fully finished yet.  i could do lxc-create /stop . but facing problem to do lxc-start from systemD service for specific user which can be addressed soon.
please anyone let me know if you have better solution to start un-priv container from root/sudo login other than systemD service method.